# Anonymous access issue in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model

I set an anonymous access to home page in sharepoint 2010. but when i open page like

> `'http://servername/Sitepages/homepage.aspx'`

, i working but when i open

> `http://servername/`

, its not working. i set

> `http://servername/Sitepages/homepage.aspx`

as home page

Comment: when you say is not working i assume is not accessible at all, or for anonymous?

Comment: when user click on home button, its asking for username and password..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the reference, make sure you follow all these steps http://www.topsharepoint.com/enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2010.

Basicaly you need to do this in Central Admin at the Web Application, then at the level of the site collection, and finally , you also need to configure Permissions to the site for anonymous users, exactly as described at the last step.

Comment: when we give permission to entire web, anonymous user can access and view all list and library

Comment: Normally yes - SitePages is a Library still, to access its pages you need permissions. In addition you could enable the LockDown (ViewFormPagesLockDown feature - not enabled by default in Collaboration site, only for Publishing), also see here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Roji.Joy/how-to-secure-external-anonymous-access-to-sharepoint-2010-sites/